# SASS: Can I get element count in one class?

Tags: css, sass

I want to position divs next to each other spaced equally and reposition them if the window size is changed. For that I think I need SASS. One time there may be 14 divs, other 10 divs in one class and I want them to be spaced equally depending on the count and the screen size. Can I get element count in SASS for one class?

Comment: Did you even look to see what Sass does?  How is Sass supposed to know anything about the DOM when only the compiled CSS is sent to the browser?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Or you can do that with pure css and `flex` property

```
.equalSpaces {
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
}

.equalSpaces p {
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #000;
  border: 1px solid #999;
}

.equalSpaces div {
  display: inline-block;
  flex: 1; /* to make all blocks equal */
}
```

An example: http://jsfiddle.net/LbxyLmpg/

**edit:** @cimmannon suggestion display: inline-block;

Comment: You don't want to use float as your fallback for non-Flexbox browsers (IE<9, etc.), since it breaks badly in older webkit browsers that only support the original Flexbox draft.  Use `display: inline-block` instead.

Answer (score 2):

You just need to use jQuery for this. Not AJAX or SASS. The reason is, **AJAX** is server side and **SASS** is just precompiled CSS, nothing more. So, you need to make it this way:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".equalSpaces").each(function(){
        totalDivs = $(this).find("div").length;
        $(this).find("div").width(100/totalDivs + "%");
    });
});
```

#### Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/praveenscience/h72horvz/